# ODF Toolkit: Get string value from cell without the comment from ods or odf dodument

Tags: toolkit, odf, ods

ODF Toolkit provides the method getStringValue() to get the cell string content. If the cell has or even had a comment the getStringValue() returns the existing or former existing comment + the cell content.

```
Cell cell = column.getCellByIndex(0);
String value = cell.getStringValue();
```

How do i get only the cell content without the comment?

Example output ('PDF' is the visible cell content):

```
2014-03-04T00:00:00
kair
media/Dateiname.pdf

PDF
```

Workaround is parsing the 'value' which is not error proof.

Answer (score 0):

yesterday I was struggling with the same issue and my colleague came up with an answer:

```
    Cell cell = column.getCellByIndex(0);
    String value = cell.getOdfElement().getLastChild().getTextContent();
```